# Android Testing - Cannot set the proper config

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing

I've an Android app, and I'd like to create test cases for it.

I've read the Docs in the Android Dev's docs, and tried a lot of things...

Here's the main structure of my app: [image]

I created the `SadAppTest` class, by ALT+ENTER over the `SadApp extends Application` class in the editor, and choose the Create Test option, see:

[image]

Here's the code of the generated test class:

package com.procode.saveadog;

```
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class SadAppTest extends ApplicationTestCase<SadApp> {
    public SadAppTest() {
        super(SadApp.class);
    }
}
```

I tried to add a simple test, which tests something in the `SadApp` class. In the docs, I read that I should get the Application object in the code by the `getActivity()` function.

I've created a very simple test, which asks the User's UUID from the `Application` class, and compares, that the given UUID will be the same. Code:

```
public void testUserUuid(){
    assertEquals(getApplication().getUserId(), getApplication().getUserId());
}
```

But this test throws a `NullPointerException`!

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.myapp.SadAppTest.testUserUuid(SadAppTest.java:14)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Precisly the `getActivity()` method gives back null, 'cause this test runs fine:

```
public void testUserUuid(){
    assertTrue(getApplication() == null);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [ApplicationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html) docs you need to invoke createApplication() before getApplication():

> The test case will not call onCreate() until your test calls
>   createApplication(). This gives you a chance to set up or adjust any
>   additional framework or test logic before onCreate().

Comment: Thanks! I've already "solved" this problem by forgetting it, and after a month re-created the full test stuff. But this was the solution, so thanks again!